# gantt chart using fusion charts. The chart doesn't get rendered a <div> element is created, with Chart type not supported as text

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts, gantt-chart

I wanted to create a gantt chart using fusion charts. The chart doesn't get rendered a  element is created, with Chart type not supported as text. Using the fusion chart debugger I get an Error that p.init is not a function in fusioncharts.js
This is the code for the gantt chart.

```
enter code here
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <title>Weekly Project Status Reports</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts/fusioncharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts/fusioncharts.gantt.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts/fusioncharts.widgets.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        FusionCharts['debugger'].outputTo(function (id, sender,
                                                    eventName, eventArgs) {
            console.log(id + ': '+eventName + ' from ' + sender+','+eventArgs);
        });
        FusionCharts['debugger'].outputFormat('verbose');
        FusionCharts['debugger'].enable(true);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        FusionCharts.ready(function(){
            var weeklyStatusChart = new FusionCharts({
                "type": "gantt",
                "renderAt": "chartContainer",
                "width": "1000",
                "height": "500",
                "dataFormat": "json",
                "dataSource": {
                    "chart": {
                        "dateformat": "mm/dd/yyyy",
                        "caption": "Project Gantt",
                        "subcaption": "From 1st Feb 2007 - 31st Aug 2007"
                    },
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "category": [
                                {
                                    "start": "02/01/2007",
                                    "end": "03/01/2007",
                                    "label": "Feb"
                                },
                                {
                                    "start": "03/01/2007",
                                    "end": "04/01/2007",
                                    "label": "Mar"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "processes": {
                        "fontsize": "12",
                        "isbold": "1",
                        "align": "right",
                        "process": [
                            {
                                "label": "Identify Customers"
                            },
                            {
                                "label": "Survey 50 Customers"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "tasks": {
                        "task": [
                            {
                                "start": "02/04/2007",
                                "end": "02/10/2007"
                            },
                            {
                                "start": "02/08/2007",
                                "end": "02/19/2007"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            })
            weeklyStatusChart.render();

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer">--- Weekly Project Status</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: got it to work by removing <script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts/fusioncharts.gantt.js"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

The explicit loading of "fusioncharts.gantt.js" is not required, it will be automatically loaded by "fusioncharts.widgets.js".

If explicit loading is required, try loading  "fusioncharts.widgets.js" followed by "fusioncharts.gantt.js"